# ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable in selenium-side-runner but not in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am running a Selenium .side file in selenium-side-runner and get

```
ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable

  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Same browser version, with selenium IDE runs fine.

How can I debug that?

Even the session closes after the selenium-side-runner test so I do not have a chance to look at the current state of the website.

I did not find an option like "leave session open after failure".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the IDE does a better job at implicit waiting than the side-runner. As a workaround I added pause statements to wait for the elements which are dynamically loaded.

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/selenium-users/XzDQ95w9OVg

I think this is the closest issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/643